# Matching columns from multiple dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with a column of ['Names'] and ['Addresses']. I would like to get pandas to print the row in the second dataframe if it matches the name and address from the first.

Comment: I've only played around with trying to match one column to another and am having no luck. I've used 'is val in dfA['Names'] == val in dfB['Names']: print val' which didn't and i've also tried throwing that in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider `d1` and `d2`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Names=list('ABCDEFG'),
                       Addressess=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
d1
```

[image]

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Names=list('FGHIJ'),
                       Addressess=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
d2
```

[image]

then use merge

```
d2.merge(d1)
```

[image]